# How to monitor Gtk3 Event Loop latency

Tags: gtk3, glib

I would like to monitor Gtk3 event loop latency, i.e time spent for each iteration of Gtk main event loop. Basically, the idea is to run a custom function at each tick of the main event loop.

I tried [`g_idle_add`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add), but documentation is not clear if the callback will be invoked *at each loop*.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably writing a custom `GSource` is your best choice.

> ```
> GSource *
> g_source_new (GSourceFuncs *source_funcs,
>              guint struct_size);
> ```
>
> The size is specified to allow creating structures derived from GSource that contain additional data

You should also give it the highest priority.
I'm not sure it will be dispatched at every single iteration, but it will be `prepared` on every iteration. To bring your `source` to life you obtain context with `g_main_loop_get_context` and call `g_source_attach`.

All in all it looks like this:

```c
// struct MySource
// {
//  struct GSource glib;
//  int            my_data;
// };


gboolean my_prepare (GSource *source,
                     gint    *timeout_)
{
  g_message ("%li", g_get_monotonic_time());
  *timeout_ = 0;
  (MySource*)source->my_data = 1;
  return TRUE;
}


GSourceFuncs funcs = {.prepare = my_prepare};

GSource *src = g_source_new (&funcs, sizeof (MySource));
g_source_set_priority (src, G_PRIORITY_HIGH);
g_source_attach (src, g_main_loop_get_context());
```

This doesn't include any cleanup.