# Python or GTK Measure FPS (Frame Rate) of the Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, frame-rate

Are there any methods to measure frames per second (FPS) by using Python 3 and GTK3?

So far, I have found some examples but they use cv2 or other dependencies. Also generally they work for measuring video file FPS. Also I could not find any FPS feature of psutil.

I do not want to use any external dependencies.

```
Python 3.8, GTK3, OS: Debian-like Linux x64.
```

**Update:** I have tried taking screenshot but it also requires some dependencies and CPU usage is very high and FPS is about 20 FPS due to the single core performance (full usage).

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641348/how-to-monitor-gtk3-event-loop-latency/63666866#63666866). Is it what you need?

Comment: I am a new python user and it looks like C++ code. I do not know C++ or C. On the other hand, measuring FPS and GTK event loop latency are same thing? (I do not know). Maybe any screen change/update could be get by using GTK but I do not know if is it possible?